# Searching a java framework to simply create a database web-administration tool

Tags: java, gwt, wicket, smartgwt, spring-roo

I'm looking for a framework, to simply create a administration tool (web project preferred).

Hibernate models are available, but there are many 1:n and n:m relations.

Is there an easy way, to create a administration tool as quick as possible? Is Spring ROO a solution for this? Or Smart GWT Power edition? Wicket?

Greetings

Answer (score 3):

I would not go with Spring Roo + GWT, and let me give you some reasons:

1.- Spring Roo setups projects based on AspectJ and a complex scaffolding of classes in GWT with MVP, RF, which makes complex code, difficult to follow/modify, and difficult to deal with it in IDEs.

2.- The Spring Roo documentation about GWT is vague and confuse. There are certain combinations of JPA provider and database providers which do not work. I think they are not very focused on the GWT setup and probably they are thinking on removing it.

3.- One of the best java frameworks around GWT is vaadin: `Vaadin is a Java framework for building modern web applications that look great, perform well and make you and your users happy.` Take a look to their 3 minute [video](https://vaadin.com/home) if you have a while. Vaadin 6 did have support for Spring-roo, see [chapter 14](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/rapid.html) of its documentation, but with Vaadin 7 they have removed that chapter.

Said that, and based on my experience, I would discard spring-roo + GWT. Although it produces a CRUD with a few commands, if your customer wants to modify few things it is not trivial.

If you need GWT, I'd rather go with a full gwt framework like Vaadin or [Errai](http://erraiframework.org/). Otherwise, If you want spring-roo, use their JSF scaffolding instead of GWT

Answer (score 2):

Maybe JSF in an option. Look at NetBeans generator for JSF CRUD application from an existing DB: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try with Oracle ADF. It comes included with JDeveloper IDE. You can easily create a CRUD application within a day (as a Fusion application) using drag & drop feature for UI components and deploy it to the internal WebLogic Server , or to any other application server: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index.html